# Parallel execution of read and write API calls in PySpark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-multiprocessing, amazon-emr

I need to load the incremental records from a set of tables in MySQL to Amazon S3 in Parquet format. These tables are common across several databases/schemas in the AWS MySQL managed instance. The code should copy data from each of the schemas (which has a set of common tables) in parallel.

I'm using read API PySpark SQL to connect to MySQL instance and read data of each table for a schema and am writing the result dataframe to S3 using write API as a Parquet file. I'm running this in a loop for each table in a database as shown in the code below:

```
def load_data_to_s3(databases_df):
    db_query_properties = config['mysql-query']
    auto_id_values = config['mysql-auto-id-values']
    for row in databases_df.collect():
        for table in db_query_properties.keys():
            last_recorded_id_value = auto_id_values[table]
            select_sql = "select * from {}.{} where id>{}".format(row.database_name, table, last_recorded_id_value)
            df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
                    .option("driver", mysql_db_properties['driver']) \
                    .option("url", row.database_connection_url) \
                    .option("dbtable", select_sql) \
                    .option("user", username) \
                    .option("password", password) \
                    .load()
            s3_path = 's3a://{}/{}/{}'.format(s3_bucket, database_dir, table)
            df.write.parquet(s3_path, mode="append")
```

I would like to know how I can scale this code to multiple databases running in parallel in an EMR cluster. Please suggest me a suitable approach. Let me know if any more details required.

Comment: Why don't you submit multiple jobs to your EMR at once(one job per db)?

Comment: There are more than 50 databases per DB server and 30+ such servers are in place. So I think it will be a hectic task to check all individual jobs if we launch them separately for each database. Feel free to provide suggestions on this. Thanks

Comment: Hmm..why don't you just have the logs written to S3 _if_ anything fails? If you want to increase the parallelism, the easiest way is to split up the jobs and giving each its own memory and processors.

Comment: The alternate which I believe is what you are looking for is to use threading to start multiple instances of the job. But this will require you to do a code change. Please check my answer for a sample implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can propose two solutions:

**1. Easy way**

Submit multiple jobs to your EMR at once(one job per DB). If monitoring is the problem, just have the logs for failed ones only written to S3 or HDFS.

**2. Bit of code change required**

You could try using threading to parallelize the data pulls from each DB. I can show a sample for how to do it, but you might need to do more changes to suit your use case.

Sample implementaion:

```
import threading

def load_data_to_s3(databases_df):
    db_query_properties = config['mysql-query']
    auto_id_values = config['mysql-auto-id-values']
    for row in databases_df.collect():
        for table in db_query_properties.keys():
            last_recorded_id_value = auto_id_values[table]
            select_sql = "select * from {}.{} where id>{}".format(row.database_name, table, last_recorded_id_value)
            df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
                    .option("driver", mysql_db_properties['driver']) \
                    .option("url", row.database_connection_url) \
                    .option("dbtable", select_sql) \
                    .option("user", username) \
                    .option("password", password) \
                    .load()
            s3_path = 's3a://{}/{}/{}'.format(s3_bucket, database_dir, table)
            df.write.parquet(s3_path, mode="append") 

threads = [threading.Thread(target=load_data_to_s3, args=(db) for db in databases_df]
    
for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Also, please make sure to change the scheduler to FAIR using the `set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR')` property. This will create a thread for each of your DBs. If you want to control the number of threads running parallelly, modify the for loop accordingly.

Additionally, if you want to create new jobs from within the program, pass your SparkSession along with the arguments.

Comment: Thanks, @Jacob for the solutions with sample code. I have a couple of questions on this. As far as I know, threads share the same memory space and one of those will be active at any point in time. Is it fine to apply this concept with Spark which extends the concept of the thread to make it truly parallel by giving them separate resources? Do you think multiprocessing makes more sense here? Please share your thoughts and if possible, let me know if there any other challenges doing it this way in production.

Comment: @Raghu Threads will share the same memory - yes you are right. One of those will be active at any point in time - not really. There will be different pools created to run them parallelly. Multiprocessing is basically what my first option is, and multiprocessing as an extension of threading is what passing SparkSession would give you. Noth multiprocessing options mentioned above would need new resources. But threading is also fine if you are assigning everything to one job (refer dynamic allocation) and can spend enough time tuning your job well(no.of threads basically).

Comment: From a production scenario, I think it will better for you to have the jobs as I have mentioned in option 1. Because otherwise, if your job breaks somewhere it will affect the load of all the tables, which is a really bad situation to be in!

Comment: Okay. Thanks, @Jacob for your valuable suggestions. This helps me decide which approach to follow. I'll let you know of the results or questions if any down the line.

Comment: If you need more info on PySpark functions, job optimizations, EMR sizing, etc, feel free to refer [this post](https://jacobcelestine.com/knowledge_repo/colab_and_pyspark/).

Comment: I use the 1st approach, and I assume in most cases 2nd approach may not run any faster, at the end its the size of the cluster that matters. If the cluster size is small, and you have varying database sizes then you may see some improvement with the 2nd approach. Does anyone differ from this understanding of mine?

Answer (score 0):

Your `list_of_databases` is not parallelized. To do the parallel processing, you should parallelize the list and do the parallel job by using `foreach` or something that is given by spark.

---

Turn on the concurrent option in EMR and send EMR step for each table, or you can use the fair scheduler of the Spark which can internally proceed the job in parallel with a small modification of your code.

Comment: Thanks, @Lamanus for your response. I want to do from the code than from EMR (which will have auto scalability feature enabled). I have set the scheduler property to FAIR (```"spark.scheduler.mode": "FAIR"```). But it still runs in sequence due to the loop-based approach. For better understanding of my current code, I have added it to the question. Please check it and suggest how I can modify it to support running multiple databases in parallel.

Comment: I tried using ```foreach``` passing my function. But it threw an error: PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: **It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers.** For more information, see SPARK-5063.
This is due to the fact that I'm using spark session object in the function and it's a driver object and hence can't run on workers for parallel processing. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Then you should create a new spark Session for each job. Hard to say how to do, but I was done in my scala spark before. I don't even know how to implement this into the pyspark.

Comment: Sounds fine for fewer databases. But in my use case, there are hundreds of databases from which I need to pull data parallelly. There must be a better solution to this problem. Anyway, I appreciate your prompt response. Thank you